# scroll horizontally to anchors and block y-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, block

I have an position:fixed arrow-navigation that lets you scroll left or right through several columns via jquery and horizontally positioned anchors:

```
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left
        }, 800 , function (){window.location.hash = target;});
```

works perfectly so far.

The columns are pretty narrow, they can become quite long which forces the user to scroll down.
Once you've scrolled down and you want to jump to another column, the js proceeds the slide animation but then jumps to the top of the next column.

Is there a way to block the y-axis of the movement?
Or tell the script to proceed just the horizontal movement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after you finish animating you are setting the hash to be the target.
This will force the browser to jump to the element that has the id of the hash. You actually don't want this behaviour because you only want the y axis.

Maybe append a string to the end of your element so that you can still target it but is not what you set you hash tag to be.

```
 scrollLeft: $(target + "_real").offset().left
        }, 800 , function (){window.location.hash = target;});
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. =) Sometimes it just takes little to see how it must work.

The function that sets the hash to be the target is actually redundant. The scrollLeft takes the target and moves towards it. As it's a "scrollLeft", it already moves horizontally and not vertically.


     $('html,body').animate({
        scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left
     }, 800 );